# NextJS v14 "App Router" - How do I access slug from an API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

using nextjs 14, i am using the app folder structure `src/app/api/` and i have a `route.ts` file with the following path `src/app/api/v1/confirmation-codes/[confirmationCode]/route.ts`

I have searched high and low through the docs, and i cant find how to access the `confirmationCode` slug.

what is the best way to access the slug using app router?

```js
export const PATCH = async (req: Request) => {
  // req.json() grants access to the request body
  const data = await req.json()

  // extract confirmationCode from slug ... ?
  const confirmationCode = null

  // do something with confirmationCode

  return NextResponse.json({ ... })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented in the [Dynamic Route Segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments) section. In your case it should be as simple as:

```
export async function PATCH(
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: { confirmationCode: string } }
) {
  const confirmationCode = params.confirmationCode;
}
```

Plain Javascript:

```
export async function PATCH(request, { params }) {
   const { confirmationCode } = params;
}
```